# What was the need of correlated and noncorrelated query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Today I came across a feature of sql server known as correlated query and non-correlated query. As per my understanding the task done by the above mention concept can be achieved using joins.

So as per my understanding, the architecture of sql server might have some predefined objective before coming up with this concept. I would like to know it.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, correlated subqueries can be rewritten as queries.  You should also understand the SQL Server did not invent any of these ideas -- SQL, correlated subqueries, or non-correlated subqueries.  I'm pretty sure these go back to the original SQL language as specified by IBM in the late 1970s.  They were definitely in the first SQL standard in 1992.

I can think of three cases where you need correlated subqueries or where they are desirable.

First, when using update or delete when trying to match rows between two tables.  In this case, the syntax seems to require correlated subqueries for what would otherwise be joins.  Actually, SQL Server does offer syntax to get around this, but it ends up introducing even more complicated ideas -- what does it mean to update one table in a join, for instance.

Second, when the correlated subquery uses certain window functions such as row_number().  In this case, it may not be possible to unroll them.

The third case is one of efficiency.  Consider the following query:

```
select *
from a
where a.blah in (select blah from b where b.foo = a.foo) and a.id in (list)
```

You can unroll this as:

```
select a.*
from a join
     (select distinct b.foo, b.blah
      from b
     ) b
     on a.foo = b.foo and
        a.blah = b.blah
where a.id in (list)
```

In the first case, if there is an index on foo and blah in b, then the optimizer will probably use the index and not do any aggregation.  In the second case, almost all optimizers (that I know of) will do the aggregation on the subquery, even when only one row may be used.